# Office add-in for Outlook - Sometimes the sender's email address becomes LegacyExchangeDN

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, outlook-addin

I am currently developing an Office add-in for Outlook.

If you use the following method to get the sender's email address when composing a mail, in rare cases the emailAddress property will be set to the value of LegacyExchangeDN instead of the email address.

[Office.From interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.from?view=outlook-js-preview#getAsync_options__callback_)

The following is an example of an object when it becomes a LegacyExchangeDN (some parts are hidden).

```
{displayName: "XXXXXXXX", emailAddress:"/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=XXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXX"}
```

We do not know the conditions under which this happens.

Can you please tell me the cause of this problem and how to solve it?

We're using Office 365(Microsoft 365).

Comment: On which platform this issue is happening :-Mac,Outlook Web,Windows, Android or ios?

Comment: So far, this issue is only happening with the Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [office-js issue # 1250](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1250). This behavior can be reproduced by re-sending a previously sent message and then calling `Office.context.mailbox.item.from.getAsync`. There may be other ways to reproduce this behavior. We have an internal work item tracking this issue, however, we don't have any timelines about it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I was able to reproduce this issue using the way you showed me.

Is this an issue that will be fixed in the future?
Until it is fixed, I'll use "Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress".
Is this a good way?

Comment: We have an internal work item tracking this issue, however, we don't have any decisions/timelines to share at the moment.